# Why does sudo call fork() and exec() rather than just exec()?

Tags: process, fork, exec

Why does `sudo` (among other similar commands) start a new process by calling `fork()` before `exec()`, rather than just running the command within the same process? `sudo` doesn't do anything after it runs the command. (Or does it?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `sudo` merely called `exec`, then `sudo` couldn't have done things like run any cleanup tasks after the exec'd code completed. Take [`pam_open_session`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_open_session) and [`pam_close_session`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_close_session) for example.

Hope this helps!